# Passing $data value from onefunction to another within same controller in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have 2 functions in a controller.

1. That connects to the form and does validation.
2. A callback function for image upload.

This only inserts path to one image in db. If I echo print_r from call back function it show all images but from validation function just one.

```
    // Some Validation
    } else {
        $this->fileupload_check();

        $data['uploadedimage'] = $this->upload->data();
        $image_name = $data['uploadedimage']['file_name'];
        //echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($this->upload->data());
        $data['uploadedimage'] = $image_name;

        $this->load->model('admin/model_users');
        if($query = $this->model_users->insert_property_details($data)) {
        redirect('dashboard/property-successfully-posted');
    }
```

And callback image upload:

```
public function fileupload_check() {
$number_of_files = sizeof($_FILES['uploadedimages']['tmp_name']);
$files = $_FILES['uploadedimages'];
for($i=0;$i<$number_of_files;$i++) {
  if($_FILES['uploadedimages']['error'][$i] != 0) {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('fileupload_check', 'At least 1 image needs to be uploaded in jpeg, png or gif format only.');
    return FALSE;
  }
}
$this->load->library('upload');
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files; $i++) {
  $_FILES['uploadedimage']['name'] = $files['name'][$i];
  $_FILES['uploadedimage']['type'] = $files['type'][$i];
  $_FILES['uploadedimage']['tmp_name'] = $files['tmp_name'][$i];
  $_FILES['uploadedimage']['error'] = $files['error'][$i];
  $_FILES['uploadedimage']['size'] = $files['size'][$i];
  $this->upload->initialize($config);
  if ($this->upload->do_upload('uploadedimage')) {
    $data['uploadedimage'] = $this->upload->data();
    $image_name = $data['uploadedimage']['file_name'];
    $data['uploadedimage'] = $image_name;
  } else {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('fileupload_check', $this->upload->display_errors());
    return FALSE;
  }
}
return TRUE;
}
```

I tried to pass the value from 'Callback image upload' function to validation function but it only passes one image not all which are selected.

Comment: The problem is unclear to me. Plz try to clarify.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: When insert query runs it only inserts 1 image no matter how many were selected.. Ium updating this question section as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make few changes to it to make it work,

1. I included the whole callback function code directly in FORM function, And removed the callback function completely.

This also helped in one other thing to. Earlier in case of form validation error images were being uploaded to upload folder but now they don't.

2. I had to make little change in do_upload (by adding $i & implode) which helped me insert multiple images path in db row.

The Whole Script Can Be Found At [SOLVED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34668072/not-able-to-insert-path-for-multiple-images-in-database-table-using-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

Try this coding ...

```
public function fileupload_check() {

$Error_bool = TRUE;
$Error = '';

$number_of_files = sizeof($_FILES['uploadedimages']['tmp_name']);
$files = $_FILES['uploadedimages'];
for($i=0;$i<$number_of_files;$i++) {
  if($_FILES['uploadedimages']['error'][$i] != 0) {
    $Error_bool = FALSE;
    $Error = 'At least 1 image needs to be uploaded in jpeg, png or gif format only.';
  }
}
$this->load->library('upload');
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files; $i++) {
  $_FILES['uploadedimage']['name'] = $files['name'][$i];
  $_FILES['uploadedimage']['type'] = $files['type'][$i];
  $_FILES['uploadedimage']['tmp_name'] = $files['tmp_name'][$i];
  $_FILES['uploadedimage']['error'] = $files['error'][$i];
  $_FILES['uploadedimage']['size'] = $files['size'][$i];
  $this->upload->initialize($config);
  if ($this->upload->do_upload('uploadedimage')) {
    $data['uploadedimage'] = $this->upload->data();
    $image_name = $data['uploadedimage']['file_name'];
    $data['uploadedimage'] = $image_name;
  } else {
    $Error_bool = FALSE;
    $Error =  $this->upload->display_errors();
  }
}

if($Error_bool == FALSE) {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('fileupload_check', $Error);
    return FALSE;
} else {
    return TRUE;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is by creating a `session` and send the `$data` in it and access that session in another function .

You can destroy the session after that if you want destroy the session